# Detach anonymous function from file in which it's defined

Tags: matlab

I am looking for a workaround for the following problem:

- Create a script `foo.m` containing `fun = @(x)(x*x)`
- Run `foo`. This creates the variable `fun`.
- Delete `foo.m`
- Try running `fun(2)`.

In recent versions of MATLAB (I am using R2019b) this results in an error:

> Previously accessible file "foo.m" is now inaccessible.

Somehow, the anonymous function is tied to the file in which it was defined.

Is it possible to somehow "detach" it so that it would continue working even after the file was deleted?

---

For those curious why I need this, it is for [fixing](https://github.com/rsmenon/MATLink/issues/102) MATLink, the Mathematica/MATLAB interface, for recent versions of MATLAB.

Comment: @CrisLuengo That was just a typo (fixed now). I am calling `fun`. It doesn't work if `foo.m` was deleted, even though MATLAB knows about the `fun` variable, and can even show me the definition.

Comment: Does defining `fun` as a global variable,both in the command line and in the script, work?

Comment: @rahnema1 No. But aren't they global by default anyway?

Comment: No. I mean if you use the [`global`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) keyword to declare variables.

Comment: @rahnema1 I understand what you wanted to try. It does not change anything. Does it work for you?

Comment: I currently don't have an access to MATLAB.

Comment: As a workaround you can read the file as text and use [`eval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) to evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`func2str`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/func2str.html) and [`str2func`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) to construct a new function handle that will work:

```
more_fun = str2func(func2str(fun));
more_fun(2)
```

Note that after this, `fun` can still not be found, but you can also assign to `fun` directly to make it accessible again.

Edit: just found a (documented) limitation: if the anonymous function uses outside variables, this method will not work, because

> Function handles created using `str2func` do not have access to variables outside of their local workspace or to nested functions. If your function handle contains these variables or functions, MATLAB® throws an error when you invoke the handle.

Comment: This question and answer together explain a little bit more about how MATLAB works on the inside. Very interesting!